# Store NS_OPTIONS in swift dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have the following enum defined in objc:

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSInteger, RKRequestMethod) {
    RKRequestMethodGET          = 1 << 0,
    RKRequestMethodPOST         = 1 << 1,
    // ...
};
```

So in objc I can do this by boxing the integer value with `@( )`:

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{ @"s": @(RKRequestMethodGET) }
```

Now in swift, I want to store such an enum in a dictionary:

```
var v = [String: AnyObject]()
v = ["s": RKRequestMethod.POST
v = ["s": NSNumber(char: RKRequestMethod.POST)]
v = ["s": NSNumber(unsignedChar: RKRequestMethod.POST)]
v = ["s": NSNumber(short: RKRequestMethod.POST)]
v = ["s": NSNumber(unsignedShort: RKRequestMethod.POST)]
// There are approx 10 more of these and I tried them all
```

Answer (score 1):

I did figure it out. It is actually as simple as:

```
v = ["s": RKRequestMethod.Any.rawValue]
```